# OutOfMemoryError over launching a new activity

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am trying to launch an activity from another activity through:

```
Intent loginActivity = new Intent(mainAppContext,LoginActivity.class);
loginActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
loginActivity.putExtra("Message", mainAppContext.getResources().getString(R.string.RegisteringUserAPIFailure));
mainAppContext.startActivity(loginActivity);
```

The new activity layout has only two images one `ImageView` of 7kb and another `ImageButton` of 11kb that’s it. Which shouldn’t be generating OutOfMemoryError?

But this generates following error:

```
03-21 21:20:14.318 20567-20567/com.administrator.myproject E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 108000012 byte allocation with 9062644 free bytes and 8MB until OOM"
03-21 21:20:14.383 20567-20567/com.administrator.myproject E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 108000012 byte allocation with 9062596 free bytes and 8MB until OOM"
03-21 21:20:14.423 20567-20567/com.administrator.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.administrator.myproject, PID: 20567
                                                                            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 108000012 byte allocation with 9062596 free bytes and 8MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:942)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:913)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawable.java:713)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:280)
   at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1197)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16536)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3111)
   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:309)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:315)
   at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:354)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2942)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2739)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2325)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7021)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at a
```

--

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_8"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_progress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/application_logo_color" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gplus_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus_sign_in_button" />


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ImageButton gPlusSignInButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gplus_sign_in_button);
    SnackBarView = (View) gPlusSignInButton;
    gPlusSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(SnackBarView, getResources().getString(R.string.SendingGoogleSignIn), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();
            googlePlusSignIn();
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = extras.getString("Message");
        Snackbar.make(SnackBarView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
}

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="2500dp"
        android:height="1200dp"
        android:viewportWidth="2500.0"
        android:viewportHeight="1200.0">

<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="@dimen/dimen_8"
        android:height="51dp"
        android:viewportWidth="346.0"
        android:viewportHeight="72.0">
```

Comment: "The new activity layout has only two images one ImageView of 7kb and another ImageButton of 11kb that’s it" -- some `ImageView` is displaying a `VectorDrawable`. The `ImageView` size appears to be huge (the equivalent of 5196 pixels on a side), based on the size of the allocation for the bitmap to be generated for the `VectorDrawable`.

Comment: Can you please show us the code of the new Activity's onCreate method?

Comment: Both are drawables, I have also added the layout markup above.

Comment: Have also added the code for `onCreate()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are using vector drawables.

make sure that they have a sensible intrinsic size set (width and height)

e.g:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:viewportWidth="512" android:viewportHeight="512"
    android:width="64dp" android:height="64dp">
```

if you have set the sizes too large, they will throw an out of memory error when the system tries to display them as it will first try to create them at the size that you have set.

Comment: Both are drawables, I have also added the layout markup above.

Comment: as i said, check the size of the vector drawables.(not the layout that contains them)

Comment: I have added the vector code also, they are little big ones but I dont they are big enough to through out of memory, because images are not very complex rather two color images, simple paths.

Comment: I didn't say add the code. I said check your sizes. My vector xml is an example. what size are YOUR vectors set to in their definition NOT in the layout you are placing them.

Comment: ok. you have posted your vector code. one has a width of 2500dp and a height of 1200dp. These are ridiculous sizes. reduce them. (Exactly as i said in my answer)

Comment: @Kuffs Does the viewport sizes have anything to do with OOMs or is it just the width and height? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Probably the images are very large, try to make them smaller. Or read [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score -4):

Just add a higher HeapSize, most apps don't work with the default heap, in the app/buid.gradle add:

```
android { 
    ...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
        incremental true
    }
    ...
}
```